# How do I make a card full width and the image displayed besid even at mobile view (usig tailwindcss)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I have been trying to display posts to a page using tailwind css cards, at mobile view I still want the cards to be full width and posts images displayed beside just as in desktop view
the code example looks like this one below:

```
<div class="max-w-md bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl m-6">
<div class="md:flex">
<div class="md:flex-shrink-0">
<img class="h-48 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-20" src="...">
</div>
<div class="p-8">
<div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">Case study</div>
 <a href="#" class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">Finding customers for your new business</a>
<p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Getting a new business off the ground is a lot of hard work. Here are five ideas you can use to find your first customers.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to remove the `md:` from your classes, that's telling Tailwind to apply those styles only above the medium breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance it worked well

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use media query to modify the tailwind default setting of your card.
create a css file and connect it to your html or if you already have it you need to
consider few things about screen sizes.

1. In what width range do smartphones/tablets come in? probably 768px is the max size of a tablet in common?
2. what is the card class name in this case its, "max-w-md" but I prefer you to use id for selecting it.

write this code in your css file

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
     .max-w-md {
         max-width: 100vw !important;
     }
}
```

lets understand line by line whats going  on here.

1. we are setting the max-width  of devices that comes in the range of 768px
2. we are selecting our card class .max-w-md (we are trying to override the setting of tailwind css which has this class "max-w-md" max-width to 100vw(100 viewport) means it will not care what the parent width or height is, based on the viewport size(the portion on which you see websites, the whole document ) according to that it will set the width when the screen width is 768px upto that your card will be 100% of the page where you see html.
3. you can go the developer tools in your browser and go to elements tab and then select your main card, look for this div [this div is your class that you want to select to see its css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIGNR.png)
   and on the styles tab on the right or bottom corder type width or max-width on the filter it will give this code
   [this is the tailwind css default setting for max-w-md class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkPQx.png)